# A sequence is convergent if and only if every monotone subsequence is convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

As in the title, how to prove/disprove that a sequence is convergent if and only if every monotone subsequence is convergent?

Comment: Hint: Disprove.

Comment: Consider a bounded but non-convergent sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(-1)^n$ has two convergent monotone subsequences but it does not converge.

Comment: $(-1)^n$ *has two convergent monotone subsequences* – that's wrong, the sequence has $\aleph_0$ monotone subsequences (for example: $-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1\dots$)